# Artifactory - increase user logout time

Tags: session, timeout, artifactory, logout

anyone know how to increase the logout time for users, by default it seems like it logs out my user session every 30 min and I have to relogin, dont see anything in artif docs to increase this time.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

A new feature of version 5.5 is the ability to modify the web session timeout.
https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Release+Notes#ReleaseNotes-Artifactory5.5

The release note says that all you have to do is set the *artifactory.ui.session.timeout.minutes* variable. So open your *etc/artifactory.system.properties* and append a line like

```
artifactory.ui.session.timeout.minutes=60
```

And your user session should now last 60 minutes.

Note that you probably have to restart your server for the change to take effect.